# Inoperative psycopg2 psql command through Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, psycopg2

I am trying to run a psql UPDATE command through psycopg2 in a Jupyter Notebook, with all connection permissions.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE dtype SET type2='"+updated[0].strip()+"' where type2 like '%"+unclassified[0].strip()+"%';")
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

The matter is, it seems to run, but does not apply the UPDATE and, also, it does not seem to give back any output (At least the number of updated rows).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-09c73e3f2ff2> in <module>
      1 cur = conn.cursor()
      2 cur.execute("UPDATE dtype SET type2='"+updated[0].strip()+"' where type2 like '%"+unclassified[0].strip()+"%';")
----> 3 rows = cur.fetchall()

ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

Which is the reason why the command does not apply in this context?

Both variables are str type

```
AOD   zabai.bde389f10d8fd3aed35fae28c5265f4b9505fab2

<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
```

Thanks

Comment: `Update` returns nothing, what do you want to fetch ? To make changes permanent you need to commit: `conn.conn()`

Comment: Yes, I had to commit new changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE dtype SET type2='"+updated[0].strip()+"' where type2 like '%"+unclassified[0].strip()+"%';")
```

Commit was left in order to make changes

```
conn.commit()
```